# Android Intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra return null

Tags: java, android, android-intent

A Activity execute below code.
Call Test Activity passing arraylist "bus_list".

But Test Activity `new_bus_list_array = I.getParcelableArrayListExtra("bus_list")` returns `null`.

new_bus_list_array Class "Parcelable" has been implemented.

I don't know why.

please help.

```
Intent intent;

intent = new Intent(_context, Test.class);

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("bus_list", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) new_bus_list_array);

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

startActivity(intent);



[Test.java]

public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Bus_List> new_bus_list_array = new ArrayList<Bus_List>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Intent I = getIntent();
        new_bus_list_array = I.getParcelableArrayListExtra("bus_list");
    }
}
```

Comment: putParcelableArrayListExtra("bus_list", (ArrayList) new_bus_list_array); may be proble arise in this line

Comment: attach  list related code

Comment: First check if `bus_list` is not null. Try this:
`Intent intent = getIntent(); Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();  new_bus_list_array = extras.getParcelableArrayListExtra("bus_list");`

Comment: How does the `Bus_List` class look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this way (using BrodCastManager)

```
   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             
                  //Your intent action 
                Intent intent = new Intent(value.equals("AccountFragment") ? "sendMeData" : "analysisMe");
                tempList.clear();
                intent.putExtra("analysisData", (Parcelable) balanceMap.get(keylist.get(position)));
                tempList.addAll(myRecord); // for backup because we are removing other data so it affect on parent
                
                // send like this
         intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("RecordData", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) tempList);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In your Another Activity where you Received Data
(After register to BroadcastManger)

```
BroadcastReceiver analysisRecevier = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            AccountAnalysisModel currentAccountBalModel = intent.getParcelableExtra("analysisData");
        recordData = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("RecordData");
    }
  };
```